# Node worker_threads + cluster + affinity

Tags: node.js, multithreading, cluster-computing, worker, affinity

I just discovered the worker_threads module of Node.js and it looks promising!

Question: Is it interesting / efficient to combine worker_threads with cluster or are the created threads automatically distributed on the different CPUs of the machine? And in this case is there a way to know the affinity of a thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been testing (on Vagrant with multiple CPU's set up).
I used `top` to monitor the cpu usage when multiple threads were running (if the percentage goes higher than 100% that would mean that multiple CPU's/cores are used.

result:
CPU's: 4, worker-threads: NO,  cluster: NO, maximum %CPU 122
CPU's: 4, worker-threads: NO,  cluster: YES, maximum %CPU 115 + 105 (two processes)
CPU's: 4, worker-threads: YES, cluster: NO, maximum %CPU 257 (for 2 threads)
CPU's: 4, worker-threads: YES, cluster: YES, maximum %CPU 122 + 127  (for 2 threads in 2 processes)

From these tests I conclude that threads utilize multiple CPU's/cores when available. So the performance of worker-threads will not be improved by using cluster.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't come across anything mentioning affinity in the docs- my assumption is that this is another OS-level thread and the os' scheduler will take care of which proc it runs on.